# Submit form with $.ajax when submit button is outside the form

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms

i have multiple form, so i create a form with button submit outside form, this form

```js
$("#buttonSubmit").click(function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            if (confirm("Anda yakin akan Checkout ?")) {
                var formData = new FormData("form#formData");
                $(".loader").show();
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'belanja/belanja_crud.php',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: formData,
                    async: false,
                    cache: false,
                    contentType: false,
                    processData: false,
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function (data) {
                       //console.log(data);
                    }
                });
            }
            return false;
        });
```

```html
<form id='formData'>
  <!-- input bla bla bla -->
  </form>
<button id='buttonSubmit' type='button'>Submit</button>
```

how to get all input from form on above and submit with ajax ?

Comment: There's no data on the form you have posted in your wonderful [mcve], so you're all done!  Moving on ...

Comment: i just give sample form on above

Comment: many input in form on above

Comment: The `FormData()` constructor expects a `<form>` element and not a CSS selector: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/FormData

Comment: what's the solution for it ?

Comment: Passing it the `<form>` element instead of the selector O.o

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get all data in the form in one instruction you can use [.serialize()](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_serialize.asp)

E.g

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'belanja/belanja_crud.php',
    data: $("#formData").serialize()
})
.done(function (data) {
    //do somthing
})
.fail(function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
    //do something
});
```

Or you can see [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184624/convert-form-data-to-javascript-object-with-jquery) if you want it to JSON Format

Comment: if i used `serialize()` , what's a `cache: false,contentType: false,processData: false,dataType: 'json',` needed ?

Comment: @wawanSetiyawan I use serialize like this code without others parameters!

Comment: hey, how to give a validation if input empty with serialize ?

Comment: that is another question not relating to this topic, you can use jquery.validate